# How do you make a CustomAction depending on a custom ContentType?

Tags: 2013, custom-actions

I have added a deployable custom action (FlyoutAnchor) to my Site. Now I have to hide this button in all other pages which are not inherit from a specific content type.

is it possible to do this with custom content types?
does it work for content types that inherit from?
For me it doesn't work yet (for default content type `0x01` as well!) With the two properties `RegistrationType` and `RegistrationId` the button is hidden everywhere.

Custom action Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.MyCustomBtn" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" Title="MyCustomBtn" RegistrationType="ContentType" RegistrationId="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900C0DEBA5E97584817AA6A2C3A0402E78A" >
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Content.Controls._children">
          <FlyoutAnchor
            Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.Snippets.FlyoutAnchor"
            Sequence="20"
            LabelText="Add something"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-16" Image16by16Left="-16"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-32" Image32by32Left="-32"
            TemplateAlias="o1"
            PopulateDynamically="true"
            PopulateOnlyOnce="true"
            PopulateQueryCommand="GetDynamicNewMenuXml">
          </FlyoutAnchor>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

Content type Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900C0DEBA5E97584817AA6A2C3A0402E78A"
                   Name="Abstract Page"
                   Group="MyPages"
                   Description="My Abstract Base Page"
                   Inherits="TRUE"
                   Hidden="TRUE"
                   Version="0">
        <FieldRefs></FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `Location` attribute `Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Content.Controls._children"`
correct? I don't see it in Default Server Ribbon Customization Locations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543%28v=office.14%29.aspx).
These are the ones available:

```
Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Links 
Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media 
Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Tables 
Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.WebParts
```

Comment: Well without `RegistrationType` and `RegistrationId`it works well. It's visible in all pages when edit mode is enabled under the ribbon `Insert` inside the group `Content`.